# How to find the last record of a user who didn't access the next day (HiveQuery)

Tags: hive

I want to find the last record of a user who didn't access the next day in HiveQuery.

| user_id | mission | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2023-05-01 10:20:45 AM |
| B | 1 | 2023-05-01 11:10:30 AM |
| C | 3 | 2023-05-02 12:00:15 PM |
| B | 4 | 2023-05-02 12:20:30 PM |
| B | 1 | 2023-05-03 12:20:30 PM |
| C | 3 | 2023-05-04 12:00:15 PM |
| B | 2 | 2023-05-04 12:20:30 PM |
| B | 5 | 2023-05-05 12:20:30 PM |

The standard date is 2023-05-06

The results I expect are as follows.

| user_id | mission | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2023-05-01 10:20:45 AM |
| C | 3 | 2023-05-04 12:00:15 PM |

Answer (score 0):

We need to get the date difference between the current and previous rows, and we should find 1 as the difference between rows. Then we calculate the total of those differences, and if it is greater than the count, the newest row of that specific user will be chosen:

```
with cte as (
  select *, datediff(time, lag(time) over (partition by user_id order by time)) as date_diff
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select *, sum(date_diff) over (partition by user_id) as count_date_diff,
            count(user_id) over (partition by user_id) as count_,
            row_number() over (partition by user_id order by time desc) as rn
  from cte
)
select user_id, mission, time
from cte2
where count_date_diff is null or count_date_diff >= count_
and rn = 1
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4JxvSJB6) tested on mysql

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I was able to get the results I wanted.
However, the computer slows down after applying it on a large scale...

Comment: You probably need to add some indexes